# Вывод в консоль какой - либо текст при определенных условиях в юнити

Tags: unity3d

всем привет. Мне нужно было сделать так, что если скорость игрового объекта равна 0 по всем осям и позиция не равна позиции песка(который на скрине), то (для проверки) в консоль выводится что либо. [image]в таком случаи я написал такой код:

```
if (other.tag == "water" && rb.velocity.x == 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0 && rb.velocity.z == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("d");
        }
```

Но он мне не нравится. Слишком много условий. Можно ли как то улучшить его?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй:

```
if (other.tag == "water" && rb.velocity == new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f)
```

Comment: А еще лучше `rb.velocity == Vector3.zero`. Также можно из `"water"` сделать константную переменную, чтобы избежать проблем работы со строками, или вообще завернуть это условию в отдельную bool функцию

Comment: Спасибо большое